# Write GeoTIFF metadata from one file to other

Tags: java, geotiff, boofcv

My task is to take one GeoTIFF, make some image segmentation on in, and save it to new GeoTIFF(with existing coordinates). If I understand correctly, the coordinates are preserved in GeoTIFF metadata.
So I grab metadata from the original file:

```
File file = new File(inputFilePath);
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
IIOMetadata metadata=null;
ImageReader reader=null;
if (readers.hasNext()) {
    // pick the first available ImageReader
    reader = readers.next();
    // attach source to the reader
    reader.setInput(iis, true);
    // read metadata of first image
    metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
 }
```

And when I do
`System.out.println("Metadata: "+metadata);`, I see the correct XML tree of metatags.
So I'm do some magic with image

```
System.out.println("Starting segmentation");
BufferedImage image = UtilImageIO.loadImage(inputImage);
// Select input image type.  Some algorithms behave different depending on image type
ImageType<MultiSpectral<ImageFloat32>> imageType = ImageType.ms(3, ImageFloat32.class);
ImageSuperpixels alg = FactoryImageSegmentation.fh04(new ConfigFh04(500, 30), imageType);
// Convert image into BoofCV format
ImageBase color = imageType.createImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
ConvertBufferedImage.convertFrom(image, color, true);
// Segment and display results
performSegmentation(alg, color);
System.out.println("Segmentation finished");
```

In result I obtain a BufferedImage(resultBufferedImage) with successfully image segmentation.
And here starts my problems, I'm trying to save this BufferedImage with old metadata:

```
  BufferedOutputStream out;
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader);
    ImageOutputStream imgout = null;
    FileOutputStream fos =null;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(outputImage);
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    imgout = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
    writer.setOutput(imgout);
    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    IIOImage destIIOImage = new IIOImage(resultBufferedImage, null, metadata);
    System.out.println("Before write");
    writer.write(null, destIIOImage, null);
    System.out.println("After write");
```

I get printed "After write". But program is still running, I tried to wait, but no results. So when I kill process the file is created successfully, even with geodata. How can I determine the finish of writing and stop program? 
p.s. Image in default Ubuntu viewer seems to be nice, but when I opened it in QGIS I have transparent fields, and how can I make gray background transparent?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, but here's two answers on how to make a TIFF transparent:

- [QGis problem with raster transparent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28214/qgis-problem-with-raster-transparent)
- [How to make transparent the background of a topographic map in QGis 1.8.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/how-to-make-transparent-the-background-of-a-topographic-map-in-qgis-1-8-0)